# Error while adding nodes and properties using jcr apis Adobe Experience Manager6.0

Tags: maven, aem, jcr

Using JCR apis while I am trying to add node and property.I am getting the following error:
**7520 [main] ERROR org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.hierarchy.ChildNodeEntriesImpl - ChildInfo iterator contains multiple entries with the same name|index or uniqueID -> ignore ChildNodeInfo.**

I have added the following dependency in Pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version></dependency>


    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr2dav</artifactId>
          <version>2.0-beta6</version> </dependency>


    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.8</version></dependency>
```

Java code:

```
package com.adobe.cq.impl;
import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.Repository;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials;

import org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils;



public class GetRepository {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try { 
            Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:4502/crx/server");
            Session session=repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));
            Node root=session.getRootNode();
            Node adobe = root.addNode("adobe");
            Node day = adobe.addNode("cq"); 
              day.setProperty("message", "Adobe Experience Manager is part of the Adobe Digital Marketing Suite!"); 


              // Retrieve content 
              Node node = root.getNode("adobe/cq"); 
              System.out.println(node.getPath()); 
              System.out.println(node.getProperty("message").getString()); 

              // Save the session changes and log out
              session.save(); 
              session.logout();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  }
        }}
```

Comment: What line does it the error occur on?

Comment: Error is not coming on any particular line.While running the above code,the node is successfully created.But it is showing the following error :"5249 [main] ERROR org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.hierarchy.ChildNodeEntriesImpl - ChildInfo iterator contains multiple entries with the same name|index or uniqueID -> ignore ChildNodeInfo".

Answer (score 0):

Same name siblings are not allowed in the repository. Going by your code, there is no check if the node "adobe" is already present below the root node. Hence, if the node is / was already created / present and the above code executes for the second time, you may face this issue.

Try checking for node availability as shown below.

```
Node adobe;
if (!root.hasNode("adobe")) {
    adobe = root.addNode("adobe");
} else {
    adobe = root.getNode("adobe");
}

if (!adobe.hasNode("cq")) {
    Node day = adobe.addNode("cq");
}
```

Comment: I have tried using the approach you told me But still i can see the same error.

Comment: Can you post your updated code with this example integrated. I'm having a hard time seeing why this shouldn't work.